# Codeigniter application logout automatically when i logged into the application

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3

I have a CodeIgniter 3 application with MySQL as the database. The application logged me out automatically after the successful login. At some point, the application returns the 303 error while updating the values via ajax call in the application. I have pasted my code below.

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'gsms';
$config['sess_expiration'] = time()+10000000;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'sdi_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] =time()+10000000;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE ;
```

Comment: What is the php version? and please show the login code for better understanding. So far as you said it logged out automatically, first question will be are you saving session? if yes then check are they storing the values of logged in?

Comment: Yes, I am saving the session and I have used PHP version 7.3.2.
Please find the login code below
`$user_email= $this->input->post('email');
$user_password = md5($this->input->post('password'));
$login = $this->Login_Model->get_single('users', array('email' =>$user_email,'password'=>$user_password); 
if (!empty($login)) {
 redirect('home');
}else{
 error('Invalid Login, Please try again!');
  `